# Cast Generic type of any

Tags: swift, generics

Lets say I have a struct like this:

`struct GenericStruct<T>`

now I have an array of `Any` and would like to get all the `GenericStruct`s from this array, no matter what the generic type is. I would have thought this would work:

`let arrayOfGenericStructs = arrayOfAny.flatMap { $0 as? GenericStruct<Any> }`

but it doesn't.

What do I need to do to get an array of all the `GenericStruct`s?

Comment: What you're getting at here is called an existential type, and Swift doesn't have them yet. A `C<T>` is *not* castable to `C<Any>`. You'll need to use a [type eraser](http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/type-erasers-in-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

I found an kind of ugly solution:

I defined a protocol `GenericStructProtocol` which `GenericStruct` is conforming to. Now I can create an array of `GenericStruct`s like this:

`let arrayOfContainers = arrayOfAny.flatMap { $0 as? GenericStructProtocol }`

Would still like to know what is the proper way to do this.

Comment: That's not ugly, this **is** the proper way. Using `Any` as an alibi for *I don't care* is ugly.

Comment: @vadian ugly is when you look at code and you cannot read what is actually doing logically but you see some "language limitation workarounds implementation details" instead.